# Where does RECAPTCHA get those words from?

Tags: captcha

I’m asking just out of curiosity.

Today I encountered several really strange words while being captchaed by RECAPTCHA:

- indelms
- sumbetat
- polietry
- grevolfa

If these were reasonable words in any language, a Google search should yield some reasonable pages that use these words in a sentence. However, the numbers of Google results for the above words are 3, 0, 27, and 0. The hits are clearly improbable typos for other, reasonable words.

So where does RECAPTCHA get those words from? (Note: “Books.” is not a sufficient answer :) I’m looking for an explanation for the high incidence of seemingly non-existent words...)

Comment: If this question is off-topic here, which StackExchange site would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 8):

Well, the answer is books.

They could be scanned wrong, from other languages, or even an author wrote them wrong.

I suggest you read Recaptcha's [about page](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore).

### Excert

To archive human knowledge and to make information more accessible to the world, multiple projects are currently digitizing physical books that were written before the computer age. The book pages are being photographically scanned, and then transformed into text using "Optical Character Recognition" (OCR). The transformation into text is useful because scanning a book produces images, which are difficult to store on small devices, expensive to download, and cannot be searched. The problem is that OCR is not perfect.

[image]

reCAPTCHA improves the process of digitizing books by sending words that cannot be read by computers to the Web in the form of CAPTCHAs for humans to decipher. More specifically, each word that cannot be read correctly by OCR is placed on an image and used as a CAPTCHA. This is possible because most OCR programs alert you when a word cannot be read correctly.

### Edit

As I said, error in OCR -

I believe that Indelms is meant to be Indians - [located from United States Statutes at Large Volume 40 Part 2](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:United_States_Statutes_at_Large_Volume_40_Part_2.djvu/990)

polietry - most likely scanned wrong from Popliteal - a medical term.

Comment: This doesn’t answer my question. It only reiterates ReCAPTCHA’s about page. Also, I already addressed the “other languages” possibility in my question, so I’m not sure you even read my question completely.

Comment: @Timwi - updated my answer, again, I am sure it is just OCR errors, if you ever scan a document, you get things like this all the time. It could also be errors in OCR from different languages, I never said it exclusively one of them.... Why would Recaptcha lie about their sources!?

Comment: @Wil: This doesn’t make any sense. You seem to be implying that the words I’m seeing are the *result* of an OCR. That’s obviously not the case. They are scans from a book. They are scans of *those words where OCR failed.*

Comment: @Timwi - Why the attitude? The man is only trying to help (and doing his best as far as one can see). Yes, they are the result of an OCR ... no one said, that OCR is perfect, and that the result is correct. Scan the book, OCR it, verify the result, if there is any doubt as to it, put the original scan as captcha. And yes, they use other languages as well - just the other day I stumbled onto a few words from my own language (very small european language).

Comment: @Rook: Firstly, there is no “attitude” in my comment. I am merely pointing out the flaws with his answer. Secondly: exactly! They *put the original scan as captcha*, not the result of an OCR (that wouldn’t make any sense). Therefore, “errors in OCR” is not an answer to my question. But these *original scans* that I’m seeing are nonsensical words from no language at all. If they were words from a reasonable language, even a rare one like Basque or Maltese or whatever, Google would show reasonable pages that actually use the word in a reasonable context. But it doesn’t.

Comment: @Timwi - No, not necessarily. Google only shows parts of most languages from let's say, last 30 years. Languages change. I have books on my shelf right now with words in them that are no longer used today in neither writing or speech, and will produce very few occurences on google/internet whatsoever. If english wasn't lingua franca of today, it would certanly be a similar case (Try comparing Shakespearean english and American english ...)

Comment: @Rook thank you - @Timwi I said error in OCR, not error in people typing and uploading - people are doing their best job, BUT, there could be smudges on the scanner, or it could simply be low quality - I found the source of the indelms one through bing search (go to my link above and you can verify for your self), why is it so hard to imagine something similar happening on other results?